# Summarize records/pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, that have the same column headings. They may or may not have data in alignment each month, but the headings are constant. The goal is to compare the data between them and produce an output.

I've set `df2*-1`, and then used `concat()` to join it to the other df (`df1`). I'm then trying to create a pivot/summary of all columns, as this ideally would only show the difference between the two dataframes.

```
diffDf = pd.concat([df1,df2])
diffDf = diffDf.reset_index()

datFraPiv = diffDf.pivot_table(index=mergeDimensions,values=mergeMeasures,aggfunc="sum")
```

- `mergeDimensions` is a list of all column headings that are strings.
- `mergeMeasures` is a list of all column headings that are impacted by *-1 and are floats

Is there a better way of doing this?

Every time I try output the pivot table, it returns:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

But both other dataframes are definitely populated.

Comment: pivots needs `columns` argument. You can probably just set the `mergeDimensions` as the index for each dataframe, then do `df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest an other way to do it by using `join`.
If `df1` (and `df2`) has columns `C1, C2, C3` as string and `C4, C5` as float, you may use :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['a', 'b', 'c'],
       'C2':['f', 'g', 'h'],
       'C3':['x', 'y', 'z'],
        'C4' : [1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
        'C5' : [10.0, 20.0, 30.0]}
                  )

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['a', 'b', 'c'],
       'C2':['f', 'g', 'h'],
       'C3':['x', 'y', 'z'],
        'C4' : [4.0, 1.0, 2.0],
        'C5' : [10.0, 20.0, 35.0]}
                  )

mergeDimensions = ['C1', 'C2', 'C3']
mergeMeasures = ['C4', 'C5']
    
dfDiff = df1.join(df2.set_index(mergeDimensions), on=mergeDimensions, rsuffix='_df2', how='outer')
        
for c in mergeMeasures:
   dfDiff[c+'_diff'] = dfDiff[c+'_df2'] - dfDiff[c]
        
for c in mergeMeasures:
   dfDiff = dfDiff[dfDiff[c+'_diff'] != 0.0]
```

the `join` function uses argument `how` to use union of index. We can certainly do it fancier but it works

Comment: Thanks for your help. when doing the join, under set_index(mergeDimensions), on=mergeMeasures, how='outer'..... I get a ValueError: len(left_on) must equal the number of levels in the index of "right"

Comment: You should call mergeDimensions for 'on' attribute.

Comment: Thanks. I'm now getting an IndexError.... cannot do a non-empty take from an empty axes.

Comment: in one column i have "Nan" populated. This is expected from the extract. But does it need to be converted to np.NaN?

Comment: you may have to populate missing lines in df1 compare to df2 (or in other way, you should try some examples). Populate with c4 and c5 to None